# Python, django: all objects in form works fine except only one

Tags: python, django

On website page user select 'flight_date', 'flight_number', 'suburb', 'no_of_passenger' on the form and hit summit button. after that, views.py calculate the price with those information and send them back to webiste page (html). all objects appear on webpage as User selected but only 'price' does not appear. 'price_cal()' works fine (I did test it - simple function). I don't know what the problem is... no error message come out. only price does not appear. it says "None"

Here are the codes at views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .area import suburbs


def price_detail(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        flight_date = request.POST.get('flight_date')
        flight_number = request.POST.get('flight_number')
        suburb = request.POST.get('suburb')
        no_of_passenger = request.POST.get('no_of_passenger')

        def price_cal():
            if flight_number == 'Drop off To airport':
                return int(suburbs.get(suburb)) + (int(no_of_passenger) * 10) - 10
            elif flight_number == 'Pickup from airport':
                return int(suburbs.get(suburb)) + (int(no_of_passenger) * 10)

        price_cal()
        price = price_cal()

        return render(request, 'basecamp/price_detail.html',
                      {'flight_date': flight_date, 'flight_number': flight_number, 'suburb': suburb,
                       'no_of_passenger': no_of_passenger, 'price': price},
                      )

    else:
        return render(request, 'basecamp/price_detail.html', {})
```

I am now struggling with this matter for several days... please help me or any hint, much appreciated.

Comment: Well what does `print(flight_number)` give you? Also why do you need that function (`price_cal`) to be created inside your view, why not have it _outside_ of the view and pass it the variables it needs? As it is it does not even make sense for that function to exist, you might as well have put an if-else there directly in your view...

Comment: actually I should have made the name of variables nicely...(like 'startpoint or direction') anyways, user is supposed to select one of two choises, 'Drop off to airport' or 'Pickup from airport'. so if I print(flight_number) then 'Drop off to airport' or 'Pickup from airport'. I need the selections user did in order to calculate the price. User hit the calculate price button then price has to be shown to user.

Comment: Well if you say that either `Drop off to airport` or `Pickup from airport` is printed then do note that `Drop off to airport` is not the same as `Drop off To airport` (`to` and `To` are not the same). Why does the posted _value_ need to be so long anyway? You could have simply kept it like `1` and `2` or `D` and `P`, etc.

Comment: 'Drop off to airport' or 'Pickup from airport' is shown to User (all other clients who visit my website). I don't want to show 1 or 2.. they don't understand what it is.

Comment: Well I assume you use `select` tags? Or even with form classes if you set the choices properly. Well the options of a select tag are somewhat like: `<option value="This is submitted">This is displayed</option>` So you see what is displayed and what is submitted can be _totally different_...

Comment: ```` <form action="  " method="post"> on the bottom <button or input ... and type="submit"> then it should be okay... it works. in the middle part, select or input whatever it does not matter.... as long as it contains objects.... then form send the objects to the place you pointed to 'action=" "'

Comment: in django, you should put {% csrf_token %} after form tag